# How can we create function for finding median of column in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to replace null value with median value in Pyspark.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Median can be computed using the **summary()** function.
If you want to replace NULLs with median in `column_1`, for example, you can do:

```
df.na.fill({'column_1': df.summary().filter(col("summary")=="50%")\
            .select(col("column_1")).collect()[0][0]}).show()
```